# How connect points by using plot

Tags: matlab, plot, line, point

The problem with my code is that it plots discrete points without connecting them together.

Related code:

```
for i:1:100
    wx(i,1)= Related formula
    figure(1)
    plot(i,wx(i,1),'r.-')
    line(i,wx(i,1))
    axis([0,i,-10,10])
    hold on
end
```

Result has been shown in the image below;

[image]

How can I connect them together?

Comment: There is a syntax error here: `plot(i,(wx,'r.-')`. Obviously it cannot generate anything.

Comment: You're using `plot` wrong. Compute the `wx` vector first, then `plot(wx)`.

Answer (score 2):

The `plot` function can only join points with a line if you enter all the endpoints of the line in an array. If you send them one by one, it will only plot discrete points without connecting them. It is recommended to compute all the points in the array first, before sending them all to the plot function at once.

The easiest solution here would be:

```
for i = 1:100
  x(i) = i
  wx(i,1) = related_formula()
end

figure(1)
plot(x, wx(:,1), 'r.-')
axis([0,i,-10,10])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i =1:100;
wx=Related formula(i);
figure(1)
plot(i,wx,'r.-')
axis([0,i,-10,10])
```

Comment: This is not how an answer should look like.

Comment: Maybe you could [improve it?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: At least, is solved the problem instead of bragging about formalities...but this appears to be the way to gain "reputation"